# download file using HttpClient in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have to download csv file using HttpClient in angular 6 inside browser itself when user will click on download method.

component.service.ts

```
download():Observable<any[]>{
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url+'/download/external');
}
```

compononent.ts

```
    onDownload(){
    console.log("data is downloading");
    this.service.download().subscribe(data=>{
    let dataType = data;
        let binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(data);
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new 
        Blob(binaryData, {type:"application/ms-excel"}));
         document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
     })

   }
```

In response I am getting this error:

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/expocms/download/external", ok: false, …}

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
onDownload(){
console.log("data is downloading");
   this.service.download().subscribe(response=>{
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'octet/stream' });
   // if octet/stream is not working then try this one application/ms-excel
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "filename.csv"; // you need to write the extension of file here
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
 })
}
```

let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Hi Yash, Sorry for your inconvenience but this code is not working in both the solution. Can you please provide me some alternative for this.

Comment: same error I am getting.
 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/expocms/download/external", ok: false, …}

Comment: can you provide me the response of you api this.service.download().subscribe(res {
console.log(res);
})
so i can identify what went wrong

Comment: can you give the example of that or you can add answer here so other developer might get help from your answer. if my answer is help you out please accept my answer